# jquery check character occurrence after element's content

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I have this:

```
<div class="people">
 <a class="deleteUser"> x </a> <a class="userLink"> John Malkovich </a> , 
 <a class="deleteUser"> x </a> <a class="userLink"> Adrian Mutu </a>
</div>
```

On click upon "deleteUser" links I want to be able to :

-hide the same link

-remove the relative "userLink" link

-and only if there's any coma after the "userLink" link trim it out (this is where i need an help!)

**How do i check with jquery if there's a coma after an element's content?**

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(".deleteUser").click(function() {
    var index = ($(this).index()+1)/2;
    $(".people").contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text()) == ",";
    }).eq(index).remove();
    $(this).next(".userLink").remove().end().remove();
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gubhaju/hCZKb/5/)

Comment: @luka see again the jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/gubhaju/hCZKb/5/) :is a complete solution.

Comment: @Prakash, if you remove `<a/>` from the middle the trailing comma remains. `var a = $(this).index()/2;` and `.eq(a - 1)` should take care of the problem.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for awareness, sometimes doing things faster, could miss things like this :)

Comment: @Prakash could you explain what "remove().end().remove()" stands for and why is not enough "remove()"?

Comment: `remove()` first removes the a object with class 'userLink' then comes `end()` traverses back to first selector `$(this)` which is a node with class 'deleteUser' then `delete()` fxn deletes it.

Comment: @Prakash i was trying to improve your method since the last comma seems that don't want to go away..any suggestion??=)

Comment: @luka can you show me what have you done so far. And Make a fiddle for it, will ease me to help.

Answer (score 1):

Given your original markup, you can use `.contents()` and `.filter()` to find the last text node that is a `,`

*Small update to fix the issue of comma's in the middle and to remove the trailing comma.*

```
$(".deleteUser").click(function() {
    var a = $(this).index()/2;
    $(this).next(".userLink").remove().end().remove();
    $(".people").contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text()) == ",";
    }).eq(a - 1).remove();
});
```

*Note:*  If you can adjust the markup to wrap the elements in another element this will be easier to accomplish.

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/hCZKb/6/).**

Comment: the solution removes the last coma not the middles

Answer (score 0):

I would place both `<a>` tags inside a container:

```
<div class="people">
 <div class='person' id='person1_container'><a class="deleteUser"> x </a> <a class="userLink">John Malkovich</a>,</div>
 <div class='person' id='person1_container'><a class="deleteUser"> x </a> <a class="userLink"> Adrian Mutu </a></div>
</div>
```

Then you can hide the whole container:

```
<div class="people">
 <div class='person' id='person1_container'><a class="deleteUser" onclick="document.getElementById('person1_container').style.display = 'none';"> x </a> <a class="userLink">John Malkovich</a>,</div>
 <div class='person' id='person2_container'><a class="deleteUser" onclick="document.getElementById('person2_container').style.display = 'none';"> x </a> <a class="userLink"> Adrian Mutu </a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure your data:

```
<div class="people">
    <div class="user"><a class="delete"> x </a> John Malkovitch,</div>
    <div class="user"><a class="delete"> x </a> Adrian Mutu</div>
</div>
```

Then you can just have some code that removes the whole div.user:

```
$('div.people div.user a.delete').click(function(evt) {
    $(evt.target).closest('div.user').hide();
});
```

Comment: the user list is generated by DB and I need to "rtrim" the last coma with PHP and this with an outer container it wouldnt work